# Proving there is no solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question:

Show that, for any a > 0, there exists no solution u : $[0, \frac{1}{a}] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to the problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{du}{dt} = u^{2}+e^{-u}\\
u(0) = a
\end{cases}
$$
*Hint: Check that $u(t) > 0$ for all $t$ and that $\frac{du}{dt} \geq u^{2}$; deduce that $\frac{1}{u}$ decreases at least linearly*

My work so far:

Given that the first derivative of $u$ is strictly greater than $0$, then $u$ is strictly increasing from $a>0$. Thus, $u(t) > 0$ for all $t$.

Secondly, since $e^{-u}$ is non-zero and non-negative, $\frac{du}{dt}>u^{2}$

Thirdly, since it was established that $u$ is an increasing function, then $\frac{1}{u}$ is a decreasing function.
To show that it decreases at least linearly, consider the following
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{du}{dt} &\geq u^{2}\\
\int \frac{du}{u^{2}} &\geq \int dt\\
\frac{-1}{u} &\geq t + c\\
-t - c &\geq \frac{1}{u} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus, $\frac{1}{u}$ decreases at least linearly.

My obstacle:

How can I deduce from that that there are no solutions to the ODE?
Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Consider the expression $\dot{v}=v^2$, $v(0)=a$, and show that $u(t)\ge v(t)$. Then, show that there is no solution $v$ on $[0,1/a]$. Conclude on $u$. Also, it is important that the interval is important here as there may be a solution on a smaller interval.

Comment: @KBS May I ask how adding in another equation would help? There's a conceptual gap for me that I do not understand

Comment: It is just a proxy for solving the problem. Also, the comparison ODE can be solved explitly.

Comment: So now you got $\frac1a-t\ge \frac1u$, and the right side can never have the value zero. Now continue,...

Answer (score 1):

Follow your thoughts, since $\frac{du}{dt}>u^2$, can get
$$\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{u(t)}=\int_{u(0)=a}^{u(t)} \frac{du}{u^2}>\int_0^t dt=t$$
That is $$u(t)>\frac{a}{1-at}$$
As a result, $u(\frac{1}{a})>\infty$, contradicted.

Answer (score 0):

if you show that the linearized operator is not invertible in the interval, then the there exists no neighborhood of any point in the interval that the original operator is invertible.

$L=\frac{d}{dt},\;g(u)=u^2+e^{-u}$

$f(u)=Lu+g(u)$

Suppose there is a stationary solution $v$

from $u^2+e^{-u}=0$

So linearized around $v$
$f(u)=Lu+g(v)(u-v)\implies\\ \frac{du}{dt}=(v^2+e^{-v})(u-v)$

So now you have a linear equation ($v$ is a known function of $t$) in $u$

Can you show that this equation has no continuous solution at $t=0$?

If so, by inverse function theorem, the original operator has no neighborhood $B_\epsilon(v)$ of $v$ in function space $C[0,1]$ equipped with $\sup$ norm s.t. $u\in B_\epsilon(v)$.

simply use the inverse function theorem.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by linearized operator.

Comment: If you mean 1/u, then it is not invertible because it cannot be mapped onto 0 for instance. So since it's not surjective, it is not invertible?